# Можно ли заменить два метода одним?

Tags: c#, методы

Есть класс, содержащий два свойства, HP и Armor, и два метода, SetHP() и SetArmor(). Оба метода работают по одному алгоритму, но метод SetHP() устанавливает значение свойства HP, а SetArmor() - значение Armor. Чувствуется повторяемость кода, можно ли заменить методы одним универсальным?

```
public virtual int HP
    {
        get => Settings[Setting.HP];
        private set => Settings[Setting.HP] = value;
    }

public virtual int Armor
    {
        get => Settings[Setting.Armor];
        private set => Settings[Setting.Armor] = value;
    }

public virtual void SetHP(int newHP, int striker, int delta = 0)
    {
        int oldHP = HP;
        HP = newHP;

        if (delta == 0)
        {
            delta = oldHP - HP;
        }

        Event(Message.HPChanged, this, delta, striker, Settings[Setting.HP]);
    }

    public virtual void SetArmor(int newArmor, int striker, int delta = 0)
    {
        int oldArmor = Armor;
        Armor = newArmor;

        if (delta == 0)
        {
            delta = oldArmor - Armor;
        }

        Event(Message.ArmorChanged, this, delta, striker, Settings[Setting.Armor]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Тут явно напрашивается некий базовый класс со всем этим функционалом внутри, а эти два чтобы от него наследовались

Comment: Нет смысла. Если бы был реально повторяемый код (например сортировка данных пузырьком) - да. Тут же у сеттеров может быть дополнительная логика...У каждого своя.....Надо понимать, что если у некоторых методов есть что-то общее по логике - ещё не значит, что это обязательно надо схлопывать в один метод. Так бывает......Если взять подход DDD там вообще в каждом контексте может быть повторяемый код и даже класс, но с вариациями....а всё потому, что контекст разный и смешивать нельзя.....Так что надо ориентироваться логикой и контекстами, а не то, что строчки похожи

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, похоже на странную реализацию `INPC`

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю чуток переделать вашу реализацию. Создать базовый класс Entity, от которого будут наследоваться дочерние. Пример реализации класса:

```
internal abstract class BaseEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    private string _name;
    private double _hp;
    private double _armor;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        private set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    public double HP
    {
        get => _hp;
        private set
        {
            _hp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HP));
        }
    }

    public double Armor
    {
        get => _armor;
        private set
        {
            _armor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Armor));
        }
    }

    public BaseEntity(string name, double hp, double armor)
    {
        Name = name;
        HP = hp;
        Armor = armor;
    }

    protected virtual void SetHP(double hp) => HP = hp;

    protected virtual void SetArmor(double armor) => Armor = armor;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Name = default;
        HP = default;
        Armor = default;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Затем создаёте дочерний класс. Пусть, например, это будет класс с игроком:

```
internal class Player : BaseEntity
{
    public Weapon Weapon { get; private set; }
    //просто пример некоего класса (Weapon), который описывал-бы оружие, которое есть у игрока

    public Player(string name, double hp, double armor, Weapon weapon) : base(name, hp, armor)
    {
        Weapon = weapon;
    }

    public void Hit(double damage)
    {
        if (Armor > 0)
        {
            SetHP(HP - (damage / 4));
            SetArmor(Armor - (damage / 2));
        }
            SetHP(HP - damage);
    }
}
```

Для подписки на событие PropertyChanged используйте следующее:

```
var player = new Player(default, default, default, default);
player.PropertyChanged += Player_PropertyChanged;

private void Player_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

По аналогии можете создать для кошечек, для собачек и прочих npc, которые есть в вашей игре (если это игра).

Есть ещё другой вариант: в BaseEntity создаёте виртуальный метод урона, в котором пишите всю основную логику. В дочерних классах переопределяете данную логику под ваши нужды